# Perl: For loop exit condition (last) not working as expected

Tags: arrays, perl, if-statement, for-loop

so I'm having an issue with my second for loop below.

The first for loop finds the first instance of ATG in the ARRAY.

The second for loop is supposed to report the first instance of TAA, TAG, or TGA in the ARRAY that is after the first ATG. But instead it reports the position of the last TAA, TAG, or TGA in the ARRAY. I'm not sure why my condition for exiting the loop is not preventing this nor how to fix it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

```
my @test_srsrspsp = ( "CCC", "ATG", "ATG", "CGC", "TAA", "TAG" );

sub orf_length {
    #index scalars
    my $rf0_start;
    my $rf0_end;
    #index value counter
    my $i = 0;
    #finds first appearance of ATG in array
    for (@_) {
        $rf0_start = $i if $_ eq 'ATG';
        last if ( defined $rf0_start );
        $i++;
    }
    #only looks for TAG, TAA, or TGA if ATG was found first
    if ( defined $rf0_start ) {
        #reset counter
        $i = 0;
        #is supposed to return the index value of the first appearance of TAG, TAA, or TGA
        #that has an index value larger than that of ATGs but instead returns the index value
        #of the last TAA, TAG, or TGA
        for (@_) {
            $rf0_end = $i if $_ =~ /TA(G|A)|TGA/;
            if ( ( defined $rf0_end ) > $rf0_start ) {
                last;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    #reports positions of found values and the number length of the sequence between them
    if ( defined( $rf0_end and $rf0_start ) ) {
        my $length = ( $rf0_end - $rf0_start + 1 ) * 3;
        print "Start Codon after pos: $rf0_start \n";
        print "End Codon at pos: $rf0_end \n";
        print "First ORF of \n@_ \nhas length: $length \n";
    } else {
        print "No ORF found in @_\n";
    }

}
```

I've also tried using a different version of the for loop with no success.

```
for (@_) {
    $rf0_end = $i if $_ =~ /TA(G|A)|TGA/;
    last if ( ( defined $rf0_end ) > $rf0_start );
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is  **`if ( ( defined $rf0_end ) > $rf0_start )`**  in the second loop. It compares a boolean with integer value. To work properly it can be replaced with

Working syntax: **`if ( ( defined $rf0_end ) && ($rf0_end > $rf0_start) )`**

Answer (score 0):

You also have a problem with the line

```
if ( defined( $rf0_end and $rf0_start ) ) {
```

which needs to be

```
if ( defined $rf0_end and defined $rf0_start ) {
```

although, in this case,

```
if ( defined $rf0_end ) {
```

will do fine, as `$rf0_end` gets defined only if `$rf0_start` is defined.

I would prefer to use the `firstidx` function from `List::MoreUtils` to do this, as shown below, although you may need to install the module as it isn't in core at present.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'firstidx';

my @test_srsrspsp = qw/ CCC ATG ATG CGC TAA TAG /;

orf_length(@test_srsrspsp);

sub orf_length {

    my ($rf0_start, $rf0_end, $rf0_len);

    $rf0_start = firstidx { /ATG/ } @_;
    if (defined $rf0_start) {
        my $offset = $rf0_start + 1;
        $rf0_end = $offset + firstidx { /TA[GA]|TGA/ } @_[$offset .. $#_];
    }

    if (defined $rf0_end) {
        my $rf0_len = ($rf0_end - $rf0_start + 1) * 3;
        print "Start Codon after pos: $rf0_start \n";
        print "End Codon at pos: $rf0_end \n";
        print "First ORF of\n@_\nhas length: $rf0_len\n";
    }
    else {
        print "No ORF found in @_\n";
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Start Codon after pos: 1 
End Codon at pos: 4 
First ORF of 
CCC ATG ATG CGC TAA TAG 
has length: 12
```

**Update**

If you prefer to avoid the module, you could write it this way. The functionality is identical.

```
sub orf_length {

   my ($rf0_start, $rf0_end, $rf0_len);

    my $i = 0;
    for (@_) {
        if (not defined $rf0_start) {
            $rf0_start = $i if /ATG/;
        }
        elsif (/TA[GA]|TGA/) {
            $rf0_end = $i;
            last;
        }
        ++$i;
    }

    if (defined $rf0_end) {
        my $rf0_len = ($rf0_end - $rf0_start + 1) * 3;
        print "Start Codon after pos: $rf0_start \n";
        print "End Codon at pos: $rf0_end \n";
        print "First ORF of\n@_\nhas length: $rf0_len\n";
    }
    else {
        print "No ORF found in @_\n";
    }
}
```